# Как сделать иконки в тексте на Android?

Tags: java, android, html

Передо мной стоит задача в текст добавлять различные иконки. Через какое View мне лучше всего это делать?

Можно ли это сделать с помощью `Html.fromHtml()` и тега `<a href="PATH"></a>`, как я видел на некоторых сайтах, или же есть варианты получше HTML?

Если по поводу тега снёс фигню - извините, я не изучал HTML, все, что я о нём знаю основывается на исходниках.

Comment: А можно пример, что конкретно вы хотите?

Comment: Вам необходимо детальней описать задачу, какой текст, куда добавлять, будет ли он динамически меняться, какие иконки, стандартные свои, какого размера и ТД. Можно по-разному решить задачу, зависит больше от ситуации, поэтому опишите подробней.

Comment: А причем здесь тэг `a` и картинки? Тэг `a` - это ссылки. Для картинок нужен тэг `img`. Я не пробовал, но, судя по тому, что в гугле, так или иначе можно заставить эту штуку поддерживать этот тэг, по меньшей мере - хоть как-то. Например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617210/android-html-fromhtml-with-images